# Check if sub string in main string, and if yes, print main string from the beginning of the found sub string

Tags: c, arrays

I've a code that gets 2 strings, and it has to check if the main string contains the sub string, if it does, it will print the main string, but it will start from the sub string's location. for example if my main string is "hello my name is", and my sub string is "my", it will print "my name is" as the new main string.

I've the code, and it is working. but I'm having difficulties understanding why it is working. Can anyone explain me please how does this function work?

```
char *recursiveStrStr(char *str, char *substr);
```

especially this line:

```
return recursiveStrStr(str + 1, substr);
```

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int recursiveHasPrefix(char *str, char *prefix);
char *recursiveStrStr(char *str, char *substr);

int main()
{

    char *str = "Yesterday all my troubles seemed so far away";
    char *subStr[6] = { "Yes", "all", "my", "see", "far", "day" };
    char *res;
    int i;
    printf("%s\n", str);
    res = str;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", subStr[i]);
        res = recursiveStrStr(res, subStr[i]);
        if (res == 0)
        {
            printf("The specified text is not found.\n");
            break;
        }
        else
            printf("The found text: %s\n", res);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int recursiveHasPrefix(char *str, char *prefix)
{
    if (*prefix == '\0')
        return 1;
    if (str[0] != prefix[0])
        return 0;
    return recursiveHasPrefix(str + 1, prefix + 1);

}

char *recursiveStrStr(char *str, char *substr)
{
    int check;
    if (*str == '\0' && *substr != '\0')
        return 0;

    check = recursiveHasPrefix(str, substr);
    if (check == 1)
        return str;

    return recursiveStrStr(str + 1, substr);

}
```

Comment: What exactly is confusing? can you point to a particular part of the code? We should be able to help but the way this is worded makes it really broad.

Comment: Why not use `strstr` to find the substring?

Comment: @Catalyst I'm starting to get it now. I forgot that the first recursion checks only for prefix. Somehow I confused it with founding generally if it is a substring of the main string and not a prefix substring of the main string. I believe in a minute or two I'll have that figured out.

Comment: I got it now. As I mentioned above. I forgot that the first recursion checks only for prefix substring.

Comment: No need to add "[Solved]" to the title. You indicated that by accepting an answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson That's true. I've edited to solved before someone posted an answer. Then I decided to accept it and forgot to erase solved. That's nice of you seeing that and editing my post, thank you.

Comment: You probably shouldn't add "[Solved]" at all, whether an answer has been posted or not. If you've solved the problem yourself, you can post and accept your own answer. Adding "[Solved]" to the title is a convention on some other forums; it's not done here. (Take a look at the list of questions on the front page.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ABCDEFG` `CDEF`

Output:
CDEFG

```
Now what your program doing?

ABCDEFG CDEF ---> Is there any common prefix such that it's length=len(CDEF)=4
No so return 0

BCDEFG CDEF --> No

CDEFG CDEF --> matches ...then go to DEFG DEF ---> EFG EF --> FG F --> G . return 1.
```

Now you are returning that point and printing.